# Icons from antd UI displays as a empty square

Tags: antd

I have struggling with one issue during implementing new components with antd UI library.
Every component display correctly but without icons inside. Instead of icon I see empty square.

[image]

Comment: Hi can you share more details like code/ Antd version etc? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have not installed icon package, antd itself not contain it.

```
npm install --save @ant-design/icons
```